# libi2c-dev, libserial-dev how to add to "Yocto"?

Tags: c++, yocto, i2c, openembedded, libserial

I have a question about how to add two libraries to "Yocto". The libraries are:

- libi2c-dev
- libserial-dev

Did anyone of you try to add it to the system generated by "Yocto" and maybe have suggestions about how to start and how to add it?
Target is to use these two libraries in userspace app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add this i2c-tools package as follow (inside a .bb file):

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "i2c-tools"
```

Comment: also for serial port communication can be used "libserialport" :
IMAGE_INSTALL += "i2c-tools \
                                    libserialport \
                                    "